# Regular expression that calls string "a?c" invalid?

Tags: regex, validation

In my user model, I have an attribute called "nickname" and validates as such:

> validates_format_of :nickname, :with => /[a-zA-Z0-9]$/, :allow_nil => true

However, it is currently letting this string pass as valid:

a?c

I only want to accept alphanumeric strings - does anyone know why my regular expression is failing?  If anybody could suggest a better regular expression, I'm all ears.

Comment: If you were curious, your regex sinply says that the last character must be alphanumeric.

Comment: Removing `rails` tag, nothing in this question really refers to rails or even ruby.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to anchor the pattern on both sides:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Comment: That's limited to one character.

Comment: Robert, I apologize for not marking your answer as the answer I accepted previously.

I didn't realize all I had to do was click on the check mark.

Again, my apologies.

Answer (score 17):

That will match true if the string ends with a valid character.  No validation on anything in the middle.  Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Comment: You probably want a + not a *, as it is, it will match an empty string.

Comment: The "*" before the "$" fixed everything.

I had the "^" in there previously, but I took it out because it helped passed some of my specs.

thank you so much for responding so quickly!

Comment: I considered +, but part of the original question was "allow_nil: true", which indicated to me that an empty string should be okay.